# How to start learning redux with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am working with react native without redux now I am at the position where I want to start learning redux but I am not getting from where I should start. I saw some videos tutorials they are directly doing codings and making some code. I am not getting how should I start learning redux.

please suggest me some sites or blogs to understand the concept of redux.

Comment: Start by reading this: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/

Comment: If you are like me that can learn from reading someone else's code, i'd recommend you search for 'react native redux git' on google and download some projects. It really helped me to understand the structure of how to implement it for my needs, since the concept of redux is quite easy to understand.

Comment: yes, thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

React-Native Redux it's 100% the same as in React.JS. So you can go with any Redux tutorial.
So the best way to start with official one:
[redux.js.org](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks, but official documentation is for all JS libraries I require particular for react-native

Comment: but usage is fully the same... Or maybe you need react-native guide first?